# Yii2 error composer

Tags: yii2, composer-php

Why Yii2 error composer, see :
[image]

I use IDE "NetBeans"

Comment: Actually that's not a 'real' json file. You may call it a template of json file.
When GII create a new extension, the program will create json file by it. so just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes outside `<?=` and `?>` on line `5`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use PHP in JSON. Without quotes JSON will be incorrect, with them it will be interpreted as simple string. If you want `composer.json` to be builded dynamically, you need to write some PHP generator class for it that will create new file, put contents there and save it.

But I think it doesn't make sense. Can't remember even one case when it was needed. Maybe for CMS modules.

Answer (score 0):

@user5717615 composer.json is used by composer. The data contained in composer.json should not change when the package is in use. The package maintainer changes the contents, pushes the package to the origin repo and users then update to that version.

Answer (score 0):

A json file is not meant to be injected with PHP code. If you want to create it dynamically, you can write a PHP tool that generate json text.

Comment: Could you please provide some more detail in the answer.